# .NET 6 - app.UseHttpLogging() does not log response modified by middleware

Tags: c#, middleware, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Web API project. In a middleware I'm copying "x-correlation-id" header from request to response. When I run, it works ok and I see the x-correlation-id in response headers on client app.

The fragment of Program.cs is below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add("x-correlation-id");
    logging.ResponseHeaders.Add("x-correlation-id"); 

});

var app = builder.Build(); 

app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-correlation-id"))
            context.Response.Headers["x-correlation-id"] = "test " + context.Request.Headers["x-correlation-id"];
        else
            context.Response.Headers.Add("x-correlation-id", "test " + context.Request.Headers["x-correlation-id"]);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
    await nextMiddleware();
});

app.UseHttpLogging();
```

I also want this modified response to be logged. I don't see this added header in logs generated by `app.UseHttpLogging()` line. When I add this header in controller such as `Response.Headers["x-correlation-id"] = "test";` I can see that field logging.

How can I log this modified http response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `HttpLoggingMiddleware` processes response headers before it starts executing the response body ([source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging/HttpLoggingMiddleware.cs,145)), so you can work around by setting the header in the middleware, not in the `OnStarting` call:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
{
    if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-correlation-id"))
        context.Response.Headers["x-correlation-id"] = "test " + context.Request.Headers["x-correlation-id"];
    else
        context.Response.Headers.Add("x-correlation-id", "test " + context.Request.Headers["x-correlation-id"]);
    await nextMiddleware();
    
});
app.UseHttpLogging();
```

Another option - write your own middleware which will log the response headers after the response has started.